# Register OWIN application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, owin

I have build an ASP.NET Web API application which uses OWIN. It works fine when started from Visual Studio. However, I am struggling to get it to work on the IIS web server (on Windows server 2012 R2).

I have registered my application in IIS as I used to do with my WCF applications, but accessing the URL results in a 403.14 (Forbidden) error, as IIS tries to initiate directory listening. 
Even the applications that are available on [Microsoft's website](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/katana-samples) show this behavior.

It seems that I am missing a very trivial step. But after hours of searching I haven't found a solution yet. Could you please tell how to get the OWIN applications to work with IIS?

Note: the web server is a different machine as where I run visual studio

Edit:
My application is very similar to [this example](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/Katana/WebApi/) provided by Microsoft. I want to achieve it that it is hosted through IIS. The application runs fine when started from Visual Studio. Publishing it with IIS is supposed to be trivial (so was my experience with WCF applications), but somehow I am missing a vital step..
I ensured that ASP.NET 4.5 or IIS is enabled through the "Add Roles and Features" Wizard.

Comment: The article you linked is talking about hosting IIS on your _workstation_ not an IIS web server.  Hosting ASP.NET Web API on an IIS server is trivial, it takes almost no set up.  Further, ASP.NET Web API and OWIN are two different things, so I don't know what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I though that this should be trivial too, but somehow IIS isn't processing the applications.

This is what I try to do:
My Application is very similar to this sample application:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/Katana/WebApi/
It is now running fine when starting in Visual Studio, but now I want it to be hosted in IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it seems that I made a very trivial mistake:

The problem was solved by not just copying the "bin" folder of my projects, but the whole project folder. Next, I needed to register the project folder as the root of my application in IIS.

No adjustments to the code were needed.